# In apache setting, I dont want to listen port 8080

Tags: apache-2.2

How we can make apacher server not listent to port 8080

Answer (score 1):

It's a very vague question not giving much detail. E.g. on which OS?  Linux? Which flavor? Maybe windows?

The way to make Apache stop listening on a port though, is to find the "Listen" directive for that port and remove it.

In your case it could be "Listen 8080"